# Python Selenium - FedEx login not working

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I want to automate the generation of shipping labels through FedEx, as we need to type 50+ at a time.

However, it looks like FedEx is blocking me from logging in using selenium but I can't quite tell if it's the website or my code.

I am pretty new to both python and selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
email = "my_email"
pwd = "my_password"

chrome_driver_path = "/Users/siddhartha/Developer/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
driver.get("https://www.fedex.com/en-us/home.html")

location_click = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a/span')
location_click.click()

signup = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/header/div/div/nav/div/div/div/div[1]/a/span')
signup.click()
user_id_field = driver.find_element_by_id("NavLoginUserId")
user_id_field.send_keys(email)
time.sleep(4)
pwd_id_field = driver.find_element_by_id("NavLoginPassword")
pwd_id_field.send_keys(pwd)
time.sleep(3)
log_in_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/header/div/div/nav/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/form/button')
log_in_button.click()
```

Everything works until it presses LogIn and this error happens:
[image]

**I added the time.sleep thinking they were blocking me to sign in because of the fast email/password typing.**

Answer (score 2):

Just encountered the same situation. The article linked by @Eric Ballard turned out to be very helpful. For me it was enough to add only the first option from that article: `options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')`

So my code is the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


options = Options()
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

browser.get('https://www.fedex.com/fedexbillingonline/pages/accountsummary/accountSummaryFBO.xhtml')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was never able to find a solution. Your code looks fine, it's just that FedEx does something to block the browser from logging in when run with Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an Imperva type of deal, like Robert stated FedEx is likely detecting the use of bots. This may be of some use: https://piprogramming.org/articles/How-to-make-Selenium-undetectable-and-stealth--7-Ways-to-hide-your-Bot-Automation-from-Detection-0000000017.html